# Como enviar un dato desde el MainActivity a una clase

Tags: java, android

Tengo el dato `mPhoneNumber` que se genera dentro del MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String mPhoneNumber;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
-
-
}

private void iniciarLocalizacion() {
    -
    -
    mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

    //Enviar a Localizacion/onLocationChanged

  }
}
```

Necesito enviar este dato a `onLocationChanged` que esta dentro de la `clase Localización`:

```
public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
MainActivity mainActivity;

public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
    return mainActivity;
}
public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity, TextView tvMensaje) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.tvMensaje = tvMensaje;
}
-
-
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

//Aqui quiero recibir el dato mPhoneNumber 
-
-
  }
}
```

Como puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

No comprendo por qué quieres recibirlo dentro de un `EventHandler` de `LocationListener`. No podrás pasarle a `onLocationChanged` una variable que no sea del tipo `Location` sin que se lance ningún error. Localizacion implementa la interfaz LocationListener y por ende debe de tener su misma estructura (métodos, con mismo tipo de retorno y parámetros). Además un `LocationListener` se usa con la ubicación física del móvil. Me imagino que el uso debe ser similar.

Digamos que no importe a dónde le pases esa variable.

Una forma es haciendo `mPhoneNumber` público, de ese modo puedes acceder a él desde otras clases. Y estático si la idea es no tener que pasar referencia de la instancia actual de MainActivity o Localizacion.

```
public static String mPhoneNumber;
```

Otra es que `Localizacion` tenga una variable pública y haces lo mismo que en la forma anterior, pero se lo pasas desde `MainActivity`. También puede ser estática por la misma razón dicha recientemente.

Y las últimas 2 consisten en usar métodos públicos. Los llamados Getters y Setters.
Un Getter en MainActivity en caso de que la variable esté en él:

```
public String GetPhoneNumber(){
    return mPhoneNumber;
}
```

O un Setter en Localization en caso de que la variable esté en éste último:

```
public void GetPhoneNumber(String number){
    this.mPhoneNumber = number;
}
```

Estos Getters y Setters también pueden ser estáticos, pero solo si devuelven una variable estática.
También puedes añadir los Getters y Setters faltantes si le darás alguna utilidad.